# emberjs add bootstrap template javascript

Tags: ember.js

I have a bootstrap template with custom css and js that I want to use with ember.js.
I am stuck with integrating the js.
I have to say that I usually don't work on the frontend side, so if this is an obvious mistake I made, excuse me.
**I want to stick with the js I have from the template and don't want to include ember-bootstrap for example.**

node version: `v14.15.5`, ember-cli: `3.25.0`

npm packages to include: *bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2*, *flickity*, *flickity-imagesloaded*, *flickity-as-nav-for*, *flickity-fade*, *jarallax*

I have identified two tasks here. First, I need to integrate the existing npm packages. Then I need to add the custom scripts.

#### Current status

**1. Packages**

I added the npm packages to `ember-cli-build.js` over `app.import()`

```
// ember-cli-build.js file
const EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

module.exports = function (defaults) {
  let app = new EmberApp(defaults, {});
  
  app.import("node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js");
  app.import("node_modules/jarallax/dist/jarallax.min.js", {
    using: [{ transformation: 'cjs', as: 'jarallax' }]
  });
  app.import("node_modules/flickity/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js");
  app.import("node_modules/flickity-as-nav-for/as-nav-for.js");
  app.import("node_modules/flickity-fade/flickity-fade.js");
  app.import("node_modules/flickity-imagesloaded/flickity-imagesloaded.js");

  return app.toTree();
};
```

When I go to the debug tab in my browser I see the packages are getting loaded under `assets/node_modules/..` but js does not have any effect.

I tried to load the package in `index.html` over a script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{rootURL}}assets/node_modules/flickity/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```

I get the error in the browser console window:

`Refused to execute http://localhost:4200/assets/node_modules/flickity/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js as script because "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff" was given and its Content-Type is not a script MIME type.`

**2. Custom js scripts**

The custom scripts have a moin `theme.js` script that imports everything else.

```
// js/theme.js
// Theme
import './aos';
import './bigpicture';
// ...
```

The imported Javascript scripts from `theme.js` also have imports like

```
// js/aos.js (imported from theme.js)
import AOS from 'aos';

const options = {
  duration: 700,
  easing: 'ease-out-quad',
  once: true,
  startEvent: 'load'
};

AOS.init(options);
```

The original theme.js also had import for Bootstrap and the other libraries.

```
// js/theme.js
// Vendor
import 'bootstrap';
import 'flickity';
// ...
import 'jarallax';

// Theme
import './aos';
import './bigpicture';
// ...
```

I had the js directory under *vendor*, *public* and *app* the import via the script tag did not work either. Importing from app.js has no effect.

Comment: the fundamental problem you have is probably that even if you include the scrips sucessfully (as you probably did with `app.import`) they will probably not have an effect because they expect to run on rendered html not ember templates. Basically ember (and any client side rendering framework) and these kind of scripts dont interact well with each other. This is why `ember-bootstrap` exists at all, you should use it! The primary reason is that when the scripts get executed there is no HTML yet, it will only be rendered later by ember.

Comment: I don't have the answer right away either, but I *believe* you should basically import everything all the scripts with `app.import` and then make all inits within components, not index.html

Comment: What ember version? Also, why not use ember-bootstrap?

Comment: thank you, your comments were very helpful for me. After some more experiments, I couldn't get past the integration problem (well described by Lux). To move forward I switched to emberjs adons (including ember-bootstrap). I kept the custom styles.